# How to use $RANDOM (linux) in a mySQL command-line query?

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I am trying to insert random values into a table from my linux terminal, but when i use the following SQL statement,

```
INSERT INTO kCreate (k1 , k2) VALUES ('$RANDOM' , '$RANDOM');
```

where k1 and k2 are of datatype INT, 0 is being inserted instead of a random value, What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k1 and k2 are of INT type, no need to put the value inside single quote, try this:

```
sql="INSERT into kcreate ( k1, k2) values ($RANDOM, $RANDOM);"
echo $sql | mysql -ppassword test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use rand() function of mysql with ceil(). Here is an example.

```
INSERT INTO kCreate (k1 , k2) 
  VALUES (ceil(rand()*1000) , ceil(rand()*1000));
```

Comment: that's ok, but i want to know how to use shell variables in mysql command line queries because i have other queries that use shell variables other than $random.